# How to get a style property from a css class and set it to another css class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it somehow possible to get a style property from a css class that is not used anywhere?

I'd like to read for example the color property that I want to apply to an animation with jquery ui but I want to avoid duplicating them again in the js code.

Let's say I have this:

```
.default-style {
   color: red;
}

.disabled-style {
   color: gray;
}

.current-style {}


<span class="current-style">Hello world!</span>
```

Now I would like to set the .default-style color to the .current-style and then animate the color from the .default-style to the .disabled-style and back on click but I don't know how to get them without creating a hidden element.

```
var currentColor = ""; // I'm stuck here. Get color from css class?
$("span.abc").animate({ color: currentColor });
```

Comment: Consider using CSS animations.

Comment: what color do you want, from which class?

Comment: You can get the value in correct way without cheating the javascript by StyleSheets property of javascript

Comment: @Naveen Singh raghuvanshi: This is true. I didn't know it. Writing my own loops for searching for the right css class however is not a pleasant task and I do not see any way to get a style by name like with jQuery. Of course I'm am able to write such a loop but I think it is unecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cheat by creating an element, applying the class, adding the element to the document, getting its color, then removing it. If this is all done in one code block, the user will never see the element:

```
var div = $("<div>").addClass("default-style").appendTo(document.body);
var color = div.css("color");
div.remove();
```

Alternately, you can loop through [document.styleSheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets) in the document, and loop through the rules of each stylesheet looking for the one that uses that simple class selector, then look at the styles that rule defines.

Gratuitous snippet: ;-)

```js
var div = $("<div>").addClass("default-style").appendTo(document.body);
var color = div.css("color");
div.remove();
$("<p>The color is: " + color + " (the color of this paragraph)</p>").css("color", color).appendTo(document.body);
```

```css
.default-style {
   color: red;
}

.disabled-style {
   color: gray;
}

.current-style {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="current-style">Hello world!</span>
```

---

Side note: jQuery's `animate` function doesn't animate colors natively, you need to add a plugin to do it (jQuery UI bundles one, but if you're not using jQuery UI, you can just use one of the plugins that does this, such as [this one](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/), directly).

Comment: Isn't `var color =$("<div>").addClass("default-style").css("color");` enough?

Comment: @AmitJoki: The computed style of an element depends on where it is in the document, so you can't get the computed style of an element without putting it in the document. (Try it and see what you get! :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder by that reasoning, wouldn't you want to insert the div sibling to the element in question? I mean, it's possible that cascading rules would apply different to the target element vs `body`.

Comment: @naomik: Not if all we're doing is getting the color related to the rule shown in the question, nothing specific to the location in the document.

Comment: I have a really hard time choosing one of the answers because I like bothe solutions. The short one because it's pretty short and yours because it's a nice trick :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder never saw inline runnable snippets on SO. Very cool.

Comment: @naomik: They ("stack snippets") were only added in the last couple of months. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Correct Way ! Without cheating the document

```
var currentColor;
var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
for(var j=0; !currentColor && j<styleSheets.length; j++)
{
    var styleSheet = styleSheets[j];
    var cssprops = styleSheet.cssRules || styleSheet.rules; // .rules is for older IE
    for (var i = 0; i < cssprops.length; i++) {
        if(cssprops[i].selectorText == '.default-style');
            currentColor = cssprops[i].style.getPropertyCSSValue('color').cssText;
    }
}
$("span.abc").animate({ color: currentColor });
```

Reference From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets

Comment: Normally deleting a downvoted answer and then posting a new one is suspicious, but in this case, this answer is so completely different from the one that was originally downvoted, I was thinking I might suggest that you do it. :-)

Comment: Some notes: 1. References are nice. 2. You don't put `;` after `for` loops. 3. It's important to declare variables. 4. Older IE uses `rules` rather than `cssRules`. 4. What if it's not the first style sheet in the dodument?

Comment: Thanks, but due to less knowledge of english i was unable to understand his question. And due to downvotes i researched about it and got solution